# HTML mobile site

Tags: html, css

i have this HTML Code:

```
<div id="header-small">
<img src="/images/logo.png" width="294" height="41" />
<p>&nbsp;</p>
<p align="center">Tel: <?php echo $main_phone_number; ?><br />Email: <?php echo $company_emailaddress_sales; ?></p>
<p>&nbsp;</p>
</div><!-- header-small -->
```

and CSS:

```
#header-small {
        display:block;
        text-align:center;
        margin-top:20px;
    }
```

for some reason, its not displaying the image on an iphone :/

any ideas what it could be why its not displaying - im just getting an outline box

Comment: Only reason for it not to display is the source is incorrect

Comment: Is the image source correct ?

Comment: If the image source is correct try resizing the image [Image not displaying on iPhone](http://www.sitepoint.com/forums/showthread.php?690662-Header-image-not-Showing-on-iphone)

Comment: image source is correct as it is displaying on PC ok

Comment: @Flowen - think that may be it - the image might be too big. i will check now

Comment: you are using a relative image path and it's possible the iphone interprets the base url differently than the web browser for one reason or another.  try absolute image path and see if that fixes it

Answer (score 0):

Yes, I have experienced this before. You get a black outline instead of an image? Like Flowen said, it is due to your image being too large. It will probably work on android devices and if I remember correctly windows phones also had some variation of border or other issue with large images.

Hopefully resizing the image should fix this for you.

edit: sorry new to this, thought it would add with the comments.